The X Server switches back to itself after CTRL-ALT-F? and chvt try to switch to another virtual terminal; the screen flickers, and chvt hangs
I have the same question on my Mageia Linux system as Why can't I switch virtual terminal now? (which was never adequately answered).
When I boot my system into multi-user mode, lightdm starts the X server. I cannot (either before or after logging in) switch to any of the nongraphic virtual terminals with CTRL-ALT-Fn, nor can I (after logging in, of course) switch to a nongraphic terminal with chvt.

With CTRL-ALT-Fn the screen flickers, suggesting that the keysequence successfully switched to the desired virtual terminal for a split-second, and then the X server switched back to vt7 (which, according to the Xorg arguments as reported by ps, is the virtual terminal requested by Xorg).

The evidence from chvt is even clearer. The command hangs indefinitely, and the screen flickers as long as the chvt command is hanging. Clearly chvt is repeatedly, and endlessly, trying to switch to the requested virtual terminal, and Xorg is repeatedly switching back to vt7.  Moreover, while this is going on, typed characters are not all being echoed, indicating that some of them, if typed at the right moment, were fed to the requested nongraphic virtual terminal.

The strongest evidence of all that this is what is happening, is that trying to kill the endlessly-hanging chvt command with CTRL-C sometimes causes the letter c to be displayed, thus indicating that the CTRL keypress was fed to a different virtual terminal, and the C keypress a split-second later was sent to vt7. Invoking chvt with strace -- e.g.
strace chvt 3

-- shows that chvt is endlessly calling ioctl(3, VT_ACTIVATE, 3), which succeeds, and then ioctl(3, VT_WAITACTIVE, 3), which fails when it is interrupted by the ALARM signal.


How do I get Xorg to stop acting in this way?
